# Load link centre jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My questions is about a horizontal scrolling 1 page site. I used jQuery for the scrolling. When you click the link in the navigation menu you go to that section, but it appears completely on the right side of the screen.

I'm very new to jQuery and I would like the linked sections in the centre of the screen. Does anyone now how to accomplish this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollLeft: target.offset().left
        }, 1000);
               return false;
      }
    }     
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML code? and if possible create a working in example here or in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a CSS question and you can also achieve a more efficient scroll by using CSS3 transitions. So rather than using jQuery's animate function, you set the CSS left property with jQuery and set the CSS up so that that element animates. With regard to the centering, you need an element (e.g. a div) as your mask with a width, overflow hidden, position relative, and margin:0 auto; set on it in CSS. Then your element inside that is your slider and is the element you are setting the left property on along with position absolute and css transitions. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/q255npgr/1/

```
.item {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: black;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
}
#mask {
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s left;
    width: 30000px;
    height: 50px;
}


var posish = 0;

$('#right').click(function(){
    $('#slider').css('left', posish -= 50);
});
$('#left').click(function(){
    $('#slider').css('left', posish += 50);
});


<div id="mask">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="item">a</div>
        <div class="item">b</div>
        <div class="item">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="left"><</button>
<button id="right">></button>
```

Comment: No probs! Plz upvote and mark as correct if you think it is :)